# Starting Multiple service in Dockefile

Tags: docker

I have one dockerfile as below.

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum install httpd* -y
RUN yum install mysql* -y
ENTRYPOINT service mysqld start && bash
ENTRYPOINT service httpd start && bash
```

Docker file running successful but when i enter into the container only one service is in start start that is httpd.

I want to start both the service automatically using dockerfile.

Please let us know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash    
service mysqld start
service httpd start
```

And Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos6
RUN yum install httpd* -y
RUN yum install mysql* -y
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

You also try to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) in your docker image